# Eclipse EE: change running icon

Tags: eclipse, icons, version

Maybe my question is silly. But when I change from normal version to EE version (for web developing), I really don't like new icon of EE version. (I like classical icon of eclipse better).

So, can we change this running icon ? (because icon of  `eclipse.exe` same on both version, just different when running, but I have browsed all directories, and I don't know where eclipse loading icon)

Thanks :)

Answer (score 13, accepted):

In the eclipse folder, look for for the j2ee plugin directory.  For example:

```
c:\Program Files (x86)\Eclipse\plugins\org.eclipse.epp.package.jee_1.5.0.20120131-1544\
```

The about.ini file in this folder specifies the icon to use:

```
featureImage=javaee-ide_x32.png
```

You can copy the original Eclipse icon (eclipse32.png) into this folder and change the entry in about.ini to

```
featureImage=eclipse32.png
```

Alternatively, you could replace the icons with the original ones and leave the about.ini file unchanged.

Comment: Changing the about.ini didn't work, but replacing (same name) the icons with the original ones javaee-ide_x32.png / javaee-ide_x16.png did the trick.